# Is there a Ruby 1.8.7 built-in to split an array into same sized subarrays?

Tags: ruby, arrays

I've got this going:

```
def split_array(array,size)
    index = 0
    results = []
    if size > 0
        while index <= array.size
            res = array[index,size]
            results << res if res.size != 0
            index += size
        end
    end
    return results
end
```

If I run it on `[1,2,3,4,5,6]` like `split_array([1,2,3,4,5,6],3)` it will produce this array:

`[[1,2,3],[4,5,6]]` . Is there something already available that can do this, in Ruby 1.8.7?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Need to split arrays to sub arrays of specified size in Ruby](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3864139/need-to-split-arrays-to-sub-arrays-of-specified-size-in-ruby)

Answer (score 10, accepted):

```
[1,2,3,4,5,6].each_slice(3).to_a
#=> [[1, 2, 3], [4, 5, 6]]
```

For 1.8.6:

```
require 'enumerator'
[1,2,3,4,5,6].enum_for(:each_slice, 3).to_a
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer! However ... I'm stupid :). I actually have 1.8.6. Know anything for that as well?

Comment: Good answer. Alternative solution for Ruby 1.8.6 if to `require 'backports'` which will define `each_slice`.