# Need to split arrays to sub arrays of specified size in Ruby

Tags: ruby, arrays

I have an array that is something like this:

```
arr = [4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 4, 45, 11]
```

I want a fancy method like

```
sub_arrays = split (arr, 3)
```

This should return the following: `[[4, 5, 6], [7,8,4], [45,11]]`

Note: This question is not a duplicate of "How to chunk an array". The chunk question is asking about processing in batches and this question is about splitting arrays.

Comment: This question is not a duplicate of "How to chunk an array" The chunk question is asking about processing in batches and this question is about splitting arrays.

Answer (score 59, accepted):

```
arr.each_slice(3).to_a
```

`each_slice` returns an Enumerable, so if that's enough for you, you don't need to call `to_a`.

In 1.8.6 you need to do:

```
require 'enumerator'
arr.enum_for(:each_slice, 3).to_a
```

If you just need to iterate, you can simply do:

```
arr.each_slice(3) do |x,y,z|
  puts(x+y+z)
end
```

Comment: Or `b=[]; b << a.shift(3) until a.empty?` (for old Rubys)

Comment: @Nakilon: That will destroy the original array though.

Comment: oops, yes, need more code. `c,b=a.dup,[]; b << c.shift(3) until c.empty?`. And can be problems with `dup` if `a` isn't a 1-dimensioanl array etc.

Answer (score 6):

In Rails you can use method `in_groups_of` which **splits an array into groups of specified size**

```
arr.in_groups_of(3) # => [[4, 5, 6], [7, 8, 4], [45, 11, nil]]
arr.in_groups_of(3, false) # => [[4, 5, 6], [7, 8, 4], [45, 11]]
```

Whereas method `in_groups` **splits an array into specified number of balanced groups**

```
arr.in_groups(5) # => [[4, 5], [6, 7], [8, 4], [45, nil], [11, nil]]
arr.in_groups(5, false) # => [[4, 5], [6, 7], [8, 4], [45], [11]]
```

Answer (score 4):

can also utilize this with a specific purpose:

```
((1..10).group_by {|i| i%3}).values    #=> [[1, 4, 7, 10], [2, 5, 8], [3, 6, 9]]
```

in case you just want two partitioned arrays:

```
(1..6).partition {|v| v.even? }  #=> [[2, 4, 6], [1, 3, 5]]
```

Comment: `array.group_by` is very useful. You can do the following: `false_group, true_group = some_array.group_by{|i| i.test_something?()}.values`

Answer (score 3):

If your using Rails 2.3+ you can do something like this:

```
arr.in_groups(3, false)
```

[Checkout the api docs](http://api.rubyonrails.org/v2.3.8/classes/ActiveSupport/CoreExtensions/Array/Grouping.html#M000826)

Comment: This is wrong. It does not split an array to sub arrays of specified size, as author says. It creates 3 groups, bun not arrays of 3