# segmenting an array by a fixed length in ruby

Tags: ruby

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Need to split arrays to sub arrays of specified size in Ruby](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3864139/need-to-split-arrays-to-sub-arrays-of-specified-size-in-ruby)

What is the best way to segment an array by a given length? What I want is something like 'segment_by' in the following:

```
[1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6].segment_by(2)
# => [[1, 2], [3, 4], [5, 6]]

['a', 'b', 'c', 'd', 'e', 'f', 'g', 'h'].segment_by(3)
# => [['a', 'b', 'c'], ['d', 'e', 'f'], ['g', 'h']]
```

What I managed to come up with is the following, but it looks not simple enough:

```
class Array
    def segment_by i
        (0...length).group_by{|x| x.div(i)}.values.map{|a| a.map{|j| self[j]}}
    end
end
```

I am using ruby1.9.2. Is there already such method, and it there a better way to do it?

Comment: P.S.: no need to duplicate answers also.

Comment: thanks for the answer. sorry about the duplicate.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Use [each_slice](http://ruby-doc.org/core/classes/Enumerable.html#M001514)

```
[1,2,3,4,5,6].each_slice(2).to_a      # => [[1, 2], [3, 4], [5, 6]]
[1,2,3,4,5,6].each_slice(3).to_a      # => [[1, 2, 3], [4, 5, 6]]
```