# Split array up into n-groups of m size?

Tags: ruby, arrays

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Need to split arrays to sub arrays of specified size in Ruby](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3864139/need-to-split-arrays-to-sub-arrays-of-specified-size-in-ruby)

I'm looking to take an array---say [0,5,3,8,21,7,2] for example---and produce an array of arrays, split every so many places.  If the above array were set to a, then

```
a.split_every(3)
```

would return [[0,5,3],[8,21,7][2]]

Does this exist, or do I have to implement it myself?

Comment: Use `Array#in_groups_of`.
https://apidock.com/rails/Array/in_groups_of

Answer (score 134, accepted):

Use [`Enumerable#each_slice`](http://www.ruby-doc.org/core-1.9.2/Enumerable.html#method-i-each_slice).

```
a.each_slice(3).to_a
```

Or, to iterate (and not bother with keeping the array):

```
a.each_slice(3) do |x,y,z|
  p [x,y,z]
end
```

Comment: Full credit to http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3864139/need-to-split-arrays-to-sub-arrays-of-specified-size-in-ruby, which taught me something new today :-)

Answer (score 24):

```
a = (1..6).to_a
a.each_slice(2).to_a # => [[1, 2], [3, 4], [5, 6]]
a.each_slice(3).to_a # => [[1, 2, 3], [4, 5, 6]]
a.each_slice(4).to_a # => [[1, 2, 3, 4], [5, 6]]
```