# How do I split string into array of multiple words?

Tags: ruby, string

I have a string that I'm using .split(' ') on to split up the string into an array of words.  Can I use a similar method to split the string into an array of 2 words instead?

Returns an array where each element is one word:

```
words = string.split(' ')
```

I'm looking to return an array where each element is 2 words instead.

Comment: How do you want to treat an odd number of words? Drop the last word? Drop the first word? Keep it?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Need to split arrays to sub arrays of specified size in Ruby](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3864139/need-to-split-arrays-to-sub-arrays-of-specified-size-in-ruby)

Comment: Markthomas did you even read the question

Answer (score 7, accepted):

```
str = 'one two three four five six seven'
str.split.each_slice(2).map{|a|a.join ' '}
=> ["one two", "three four", "five six", "seven"]
```

This also handles the case of an odd number of words.

Comment: I'm trying to figure out how I can reduce this to something like `str.split.each_slice(2).map(&:join)` but I can't get the `' '` argument on the `join`.

Comment: Joe: It's better to open a separate question. Hint: not &: but instead inline {|t|t.join(' ')}

Comment: Thank you for the comment @SimonB. but the comment was mostly my own comment to myself about my own answer. The answer reflects your hint already, I was trying to make this more terse.

Answer (score 4):

You can do

```
string= 'one1! two2@ three3# four4$ five5% six6^ sev'
string.scan(/\S+ ?\S*/)
# => ["one1! two2@", "three3# four4$", "five5% six6^", "sev"]
```

Comment: Not if the last word is a single character.

Comment: is you replace the ` ?` with `\s*`, then it will also preserve the original whitespace between the words.

Comment: @JoshuaCheek Sorry I don't get it. What do you mean by the original whitespace?

Comment: @oldergod if it was `"one1!\t      two2@"`, this would retain the tab and extra spaces (SO is only displaying one space in the example, but pretend there were many)

Answer (score 3):

Something like this should work:

```
string.scan(/\w+ \w+/)
```

Comment: `str = 'one1! two2@ three3# four4$ five5% six6^'` outputs `[]`. I don't know if the words are all alphabetic

Comment: maybe `string.scan(/\S+ \S+/)` would be better.

Comment: It's also unanswered how to tread an odd number of words. I dunno.

Comment: Probably `/\S+\s+\S+/` because you don't necessarily know that it's one space between words.

Comment: OP isn't responding, it could be that they literally want to split on spaces. Who knows... I'm not spending more time on this.

Comment: This fails the simple test of `'a b c'.scan(/\w+ \w+/)
=> ["a b"]`

Comment: It is unanswered how to treat an odd number of words.

Answer (score 2):

Ruby's `scan` is useful for this:

```
'a b c'.scan(/\w+(?:\s+\w+)?/)
=> ["a b", "c"]

'a b c d e f g'.scan(/\w+(?:\s+\w+)?/)
=> ["a b", "c d", "e f", "g"]
```

Answer (score 2):

This is all I had to do:

```
def first_word
    chat = "I love Ruby"
    chat = chat.split(" ")
    chat[0]
end
```