# Rails Dividing Array and Assigning to Value

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

In my Rails 4 app, I have submitted `Questions`.  What I want to do is to shuffle the order of the `Questions`, divide the list into seven (for the next seven days), and then save these `Questions` with a publish_date.

The `publish_dates` would be the next 7 days (i.e. `Date.current+1`, `Date.current+2`, `Date.current+3`, `Date.current+4`, `Date.current+5`, `Date.current+6`, `Date.current+7`).

I understand that I can shuffle the records with `@questions.shuffle`, but I don't know how to divide the results by seven (I know that since the number of `Questions` won't always be divisible by 7, some days may end up with one additional `Question`), and how to assign those to a `publish_date`.

Thank you in advance for any help!

---

UPDATE

It sounds like I just need to use `in_groups_of` to divide the results.  What I don't understand now is how to assign the groups to the dates.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to split (chunk) a Ruby array into parts of X elements?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2699584/how-to-split-chunk-a-ruby-array-into-parts-of-x-elements)

Comment: Thanks @BradWerth.  It sounds like I can use in_groups_of.  What I don't understand now, is how to assign those groups to dates.

Comment: I'm sorry, I picked the wrong one, you probably want http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3864139/need-to-split-arrays-to-sub-arrays-of-specified-size-in-ruby

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You already figured out how to get your groups. To set the publish date for the group elements, you can do something like this:

```
questions.map.with_index(1) do |question, i|
  question.update(publish_date: Date.current + i
end
```

This is assuming that `questions` are an AR model and `publish_date` is an actual attribute.

Comment: Thanks!  Yes, `Questions` is an AR model and `publish_date` is an actual attribute.  I must've did something wrong.  I did `@questions.shuffle`, `@questions.in_groups_of(3)` and then `@questions.map.with_index(1) do |question, i|
  question.update(publish_date: Date.current + i)
end` but all of the `questions` just ended up with Date.current + i (tomorrow) as the publish_date.  What did I do wrong?

Comment: Sorry, I realized that I might need to change the number after `with_index` to `(7)`.  When I did that, the `publish_date` was different for the `questions`, but it seem to not take into consideration the groups.  I selected 9 `questions`, but instead of just assigning them to the next 7 days, it assigned to the next 9 days.  I must be missing something between @questions.in_groups_of(3) and your code, but I'm unsure what.

Comment: `@questions.in_groups_of(3)` gives you an array of 3 element arrays. So you need to iterate over the groups. I.e. something like `@questions.in_groups_of(3).each { |group| group.map.with_index... }`

Answer (score 0):

Since you're shuffling the records you don't have to worry about which order they're in. Just deal them out until your stack of questions is exhausted:

```
# Represent questions here as numbers
questions = (1..15).to_a

# Create an array to collect answers for each day of the week
days = Array.new(7) { [ ] }

# Deal out each of the questions to a day of the week
questions.each_with_index do |q, i|
  days[i % 7] << q
end

# Scramble things just to introduce a bit of variety
days.shuffle!

days
# => [[3, 10], [4, 11], [2, 9], [1, 8, 15], [6, 13], [5, 12], [7, 14]]
```

This way you'll get a fairly even mix of questions across the given days but without them all being front-loaded on the beginning of the week if there's a non multiple of seven number of them.

I don't think this is possible to do with things like `each_slice` since the number of questions each day will vary.